# Fill jtable using calendar start date and end date

Tags: java, swing, date

Starting date is today and end date should be today's date  +3 years
Example:

```
TODAY=3.1.2013 and
END DATE=3.1.2016
```

This is the screenshot

[image]
    ;

```
    Date begindate = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(begindate);
    int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 3);
    Date enddate = cal.getTime();
    Date currentdate = begindate;
    while (true) {
        if (currentdate.getTime() >= enddate.getTime()) {
            break;
        } else {
        }
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(begindate);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, x++);
        Date newdate = c.getTime();
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        currentdate = newdate;
    }
```

Comment: question is not clear... can u update it.. Kindly have a look http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#addYears(java.util.Date, int)

Comment: http://i43.tinypic.com/2cygryg.jpg
 like  this image

Comment: Could you show us what you've attempted? Or what particular part you're having trouble with?

Comment: i cant assign while loop values to an 2D array to fill the table

Comment: thanks.but i want to fill the table using every date between Fri Jan 03 08:53:44 IST 2014 and
Tue Jan 03 08:53:44 IST 2017 .
one cell should contain one date

Comment: Could you explain the scenario, because i am unable to view the image

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eLR7F.jpg this is image

Comment: i want to fill the Jtable using 2D array. How to modify this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, rather than trying to calculate EVERY `Date` up front, instead, you can dynamically calculate the values as required...

I should add, this is just one possible approach...

Basically, using the start and end dates, you can calculate the number of days between them, calculate the number of rows you need and then when required, calculate the `Date` from the start of the calendar based on the current row and column.

The following example uses [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to perform many of the date calculations as it's more reliable and easier to use then Java's in built `Calendar` (IMHO)

[image: Start][image: End]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants;
import org.joda.time.Days;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.MutableDateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class BuildCalendar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BuildCalendar();
    }

    public BuildCalendar() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM.dd.yyyy");
                DateTime startDate = dtf.parseDateTime("3.1.2013");
                DateTime endDate = dtf.parseDateTime("3.1.2016");

                JTable table = new JTable(new CalendarModel(startDate, endDate));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class CalendarModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        public static String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

        private int rows = 0;

        private MutableDateTime startOfWeek;
        private DateTime startDate;
        private DateTime endDate;

        public CalendarModel(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
            this.startDate = startDate;
            this.endDate = endDate;

            int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays();
            if (days > 0) {

                startOfWeek = new MutableDateTime(startDate);
                while (startOfWeek.getDayOfWeek() != DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY) {

                    startOfWeek.addDays(-1);

                }

                int offset = Days.daysBetween(startOfWeek, startDate).getDays();
                days += offset;

                System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(days / 7d));
                rows = (int) Math.round(days / 7d) + 1;
                System.out.println(rows);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 7;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return Date.class;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

            Date date = null;

            if (startOfWeek != null) {

                MutableDateTime dt = new MutableDateTime(startOfWeek);
                int day = (rowIndex * 7) + columnIndex;
                dt.addDays(day);

                if (dt.isBefore(startDate) || dt.isAfter(endDate)) {

                    date = null;

                } else {

                    date = dt.toDate();

                }

            }

            return date;

        }

    }

}
```

**Updated with `Calendar` example**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class BuildCalendar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BuildCalendar();
    }

    public BuildCalendar() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy");
                    Date startDate = sdf.parse("3.1.2013");
                    Date endDate = sdf.parse("3.1.2016");

                    JTable table = new JTable(new CalendarModel(startDate, endDate));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (ParseException | HeadlessException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class CalendarModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        public static String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

        private int rows = 0;

        private Date startOfWeek;
        private Date startDate;
        private Date endDate;

        public CalendarModel(Date startDate, Date endDate) {

            this.startDate = startDate;
            this.endDate = endDate;

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(startDate);
            while (cal.getTime().before(endDate)) {
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
                rows++;
            }
            rows++;

            if (rows > 0) {

                int offset = 0;
                cal.setTime(startDate);
                while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {

                    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                    offset++;

                }

                startOfWeek = cal.getTime();
                System.out.println("Start @ " + cal.getTime());
                System.out.println("rows = " + rows);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 7;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return Date.class;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

            Date date = null;

            if (startOfWeek != null) {

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(startOfWeek);
                int day = (rowIndex * 7) + columnIndex;
                System.out.println("day = " + day);
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, day);

                if (cal.getTime().before(startDate) || cal.getTime().after(endDate)) {

                    date = null;

                } else {

                    date = cal.getTime();
                    System.out.println("Real date = " + date);

                }

            }

            return date;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks.cant we implement this without JODA time?

Comment: It's possible, but, it takes more code and becomes less reliable over time.

Comment: I've added an example using `Calendar`.  Note, instead of trying to do calculations to determine the number of days, I literally walk through the `Calendar` because time calculations are unreliable the further the dates get apart, you should always uses some kind of reliable date API...like JodaTime ;)

Comment: So? A JFrame is just a container like JPanel. You really only require the table model, the rest is just there to support it...

Comment: i want to fill the Jtable using 2D array. How to modify this code?

Comment: Well, there you have some problems.  The first is accurately calculating the number of rows you need.  You also need consider what to do with values that fall after the start of the week and before the end of the week

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)` constructor.
In order to build the rowData, first create a map of day-of-week and dates:

```
    Map<Integer, List<Date>> dateMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<Date>>();
    //Initialize
    for (int i = Calendar.SUNDAY; i <= Calendar.SATURDAY; ++i) {
        dateMap.put(i, new ArrayList<Date>());
    }
```

Within the loop, add values to the map:

```
dateMap.get(day).add(currentdate);
```

Before constructing the `JTable`, convert the `dateMap` to `Object[][]`